# C# - NullReferenceException when attempting to parse a string to float in an array

Tags: c#, arrays

This is blowing my mind right now, I don't know what I'm doing wrong.
What I'm attempting to do is grab the contents of a textbox, splitting values separated by a comma, putting them into an array and then parsing them to float and put them into another array. 
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
        Xt = s1.Split(',').Select(s1V => s1V.Trim()).ToArray();
        Yt = s2.Split(',').Select(s2V => s2V.Trim()).ToArray();
        float number;
        if (Xt.Length == Yt.Length)
        {
            int i = 0;
            foreach (var value in Xt)
            {
                // Console.WriteLine("l:"+Xt.Length+" "+Xt[i]+"+");
                if (Xt[i] != null)
                {
                    Xi[i] = float.Parse(Xt[i]);
                }
                //  Yi[i] = float.Parse(Yt[i]);
                i++;
            }
 ...
```

Comment: How is `Xi` defined? Did you initialize it?

Comment: Well I defined it globally as "float[] Xi;"
And no, didn't initialize it, is that what's causing my problem?

Comment: Yes. Assign `Xi = new float[Xt.Length];` before entering the loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
string s1 = textBox1.Text;
        string s2 = textBox2.Text;            
        float[] Yi;
        Xt = s1.Split(',').Select(s1V => s1V.Trim()).ToArray();
        Yt = s2.Split(',').Select(s2V => s2V.Trim()).ToArray();
        float number;
        if (Xt.Length == Yt.Length)
        {
            int i = 0;
            Xi = new float[Xt.Length];//<---properly initializing the array.
            foreach (var value in Xt)
            {

                // Console.WriteLine("l:"+Xt.Length+" "+Xt[i]+"+");
                if (Xt[i] != null)
                {
                    Xi[i] = float.Parse(Xt[i]);
                }
                //  Yi[i] = float.Parse(Yt[i]);
                i++;

            }
```

Thanks to MarcinJuraszek.